# Do deleted comments disappear from the targeted user's inbox?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments, global-inbox

Suppose someone posts a comment to one of my questions. I guess that comment would then appear in my SO inbox.

Now suppose the commenter deletes their comment. Will the comment also disappear from my inbox? Or will it only be removed from the question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they disappear, see e.g. [this Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65792/295232) by @KevinMontrose:

> Deletions are now reflected* in the inbox.
>
> There is, of course, a natural race condition; wherein you load a page with a notice right before the originating user deletes the answer/comment. That's not going to be addressed.